# Scrubbing HTML5 video on touch devices

Tags: javascript, video

How to optimize the process of scrubbing video for touchscreen devices?
For the mouse, everything works successfully, using mousedown mousemove events. But scrubbing doesn't work on iPad.

```
var paused;
var shiftX;

progressBar.addEventListener('mousedown', startScrubbing);

function startScrubbing(e) {
    paused = video.paused;
    if (!paused) video.pause();
    shiftX = e.pageX - e.offsetX;
    scrubbing(e);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', scrubbing);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopScrubbing);
}

function scrubbing(e) {
    video.currentTime = ((e.pageX - shiftX) / progressBar.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
}

function stopScrubbing() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', scrubbing);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopScrubbing);
    if (!paused) video.play();
}
```

Example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/creo_ev/pen/ZZGMZL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to use events for the touch display: touchstart, touchmove, touchend. And also I used the experimental parameter e.offsetX for nothing, which is not returned for touch events. To listen multiple events, use .on from jQuery. Here is the final code:

```
var paused;
var shiftX = progressBar.getBoundingClientRect().left;

$('.progress-bar').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    paused = video.paused;
    if (!paused) video.pause();
    scrubbing(e);
    $(document).on('mousemove touchmove', scrubbing);
    $(document).on('mouseup touchend', function() {
        $(document).off('mousemove touchmove');
        $(document).off('mouseup touchend');
        if (!paused) video.play();
    });
});

function scrubbing(e) {
    video.currentTime = ((e.pageX - shiftX) / progressBar.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/creo_ev/pen/QPNREP)